# how to get data in ng dialog angularjs using http method?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ajax

Getting Data from database with php. Data is fine. Butt data is not showing in NgModel box. I have passed scope parameter in ngdialog function. Please help me out.

```js
var adminapp = angular.module("uibootstrap", ["ngRoute", 'ngDialog']);
adminapp.controller("homedata", function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike, ngDialog, $timeout) {

  $rootScope.theme = 'ngdialog-theme-default';

  $scope.openDefault = function() {
    ngDialog.open({
      template: 'firstDialogId',
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
      scope: $scope
    })
  };
  // get user
  $http.get('http://localhost/database/get-user.php').success(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<li ng-repeat="item in users">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="openDefault()">
    <div class="img"><img alt="" src="admin/images/user-img2.jpg"> <span class="status-red"></span></div>
    <div class="msginfo">
      {{item.user_name}} <br> <span>{{item.user_status}}</span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="firstDialogId">
    <div class="ngdialog-message">
      <div class="data">
        <div class="img">
          <img alt="" src="http://localhost/rockeditor/admin/images/img-user.png"> <a class="editbtn" href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="name">{{item.user_name}}</div>
        <span class="editor">{{item.user_status}}</span>
        <span class="email">{{item.user_email}}</span>
        <input class="btn-green" type="submit" value="Save">
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</li>
```

Comment: Is your dialog is opening?

Comment: yes opening fine. but empty. value is showing fine out of the model box.

Answer (score 0):

variable `item` is not available in your template `firstDialogId`, actually it's not a child node of `<li></li>`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to include `controller` in your html.

- Use `ng-controller="homedata"` on `<li>` element
- `item` is not accessible in that `script` tag
- `$scope.users` is available after `$http` call returned with success response

See here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ngDialog.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ngDialog-theme-default.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="ngDialog.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="homedata">


  <button ng-click="clickme()">Hello World</button>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="firstDialogId">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <div>Current user:</div>
      <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
// Code goes here
angular.module("MyApp", ['ngDialog'])
  .controller("homedata", homedata)

function Main($scope, ngDialog) {
  $scope.users = [
      {name: 'abc'},
      {name: 'xyz'}
    ];
  $scope.clickme = function() {
    ngDialog.open({
      template: 'firstDialogId',
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
      scope: $scope
    });

  };
}
```

But as per your controller, There is a `$http` call and until it responded you don't have any data in `$scope.users`. So, please make sure that it and you only get data in your dialog after the `$http` is get success response